# How to add Category image programmatically?

Tags: magento

I am trying to add category programatically. Category got created very easily but i am not finding the way to add category image.
here is my code.

```
    $brand_name = $_POST['brand_name'];
    $brand_logo = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $brand_content = $_POST['brand_content'];
    $brand_id = $_POST['brand_id'];
    $brand_path = $brand_logo;

    $parentId = '35';

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->setName($brand_name);
    $category->setUrlKey($brand_name);
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(0);




    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

$data['display_mode'] = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE';
$data['page_layout'] = 'one_column';
$data['thumbnail'] = $brand_path;
$category->addData($data);

    $category->save();
    unset($category);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You already have the part which add image for your cat. It's:

```
$data['thumbnail'] = $brand_path;
```

But I'm sure that $brand_path = $brand_logo = $_FILES['filename']['name'] contains wrong value for cat thumbnail parameter.

$data['thumbnail'] should contains image path, not only the image name.

Comment: Hello Yaroslav Rogoza thanks for your quick reply i have also tried giving the path directly like : $data ['thumbnail'] = http://localhost/bif/media/catalog/category/image_name.jpg and image exist here

Comment: There are two images for category. Image and Thumbnail. Try to use $data['image']